# Selection Path of a JTree

Tags: java, swing, xsd, selection, jtree

I've loaded a JTree with nodes from an XML Schema file using the XSOM API (https://xsom.dev.java.net).

Every time a file is selected I do the folowing:

```
schemaParser = new XSDParser(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

TreeModel model = schemaParser.generateTreeModel();
schemaTree.setModel(model);
schemaTree.setCellRenderer(new SchemaTreeTraverser.SchemaTreeCellRenderer());
```

schemaTree is the variable name for the JTree.

The code for XSDParser is as follows:

```
package schemaparser;

import java.io.*;
import com.sun.xml.xsom.XSSchemaSet;
import com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.util.SchemaTreeTraverser;
import com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.util.SchemaWriter;
import com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser;

import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;

public class XSDParser {

    private XSOMParser reader;
    private XSSchemaSet xss;

    public XSDParser(String parseFile){
        try {
            reader = new XSOMParser();
            reader.parse(new File(parseFile));

            xss = reader.getResult();
            if (xss == null) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   public TreeModel generateTreeModel() {
        SchemaTreeTraverser stt = new SchemaTreeTraverser();
        stt.visit(xss);
        TreeModel model = stt.getModel();

        System.out.println("Returning the tree model");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Now whenever a node is selected in the JTree I do the following:

```
private void schemaTreeValueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt)      {                                        

        TreePath path = schemaTree.getSelectionPath();

        if(path != null)
            System.out.println(path.toString());

}
```

However now no matter which node I select in the tree I get something like: [null, null, null, null] (depending on how far the hierarchy I go)

For a simple JTree this would usually print out the path to the node, e.g.: [JTree, colors, red]

Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: You need to provide more information about XSDParser and SchemaTreeTraverser.SchemaTreeCellRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be asking the `JTree` for the selected paths, you should get them from the `TreeSelectionEvent`.